# Can I select more than 1 row in a database with varying identifiers?

Tags: php, mysql

Can I select more than 1 row in a database with  varying identifiers?

```
SELECT * FROM `views` WHERE `img_id` =52 and where 'img_id' =123 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This should return all rows where above mentioned image ids occur.

In some cases this may be looking for 10 - 20 identifiers

Comment: Are you sure you mean `AND` or should it be `OR` in your query?

Comment: What you want is [an `IN ()` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in). You can have only one `WHERE` keyword, though it may have multiple conditions grouped with logical `AND,OR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query you probably want to write:

```
SELECT *
FROM `views`
WHERE `img_id` = 52 or img_id = 123
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This removes the second `where`, which is syntactically incorrect.  It also removed the single quotes from `image_id`, which cause that to be treated as a string constant.  Only use single quotes for string constants.  Never use them for identifiers for tables name and column names.

By the way, you can more simply write this as:

```
SELECT *
FROM `views`
WHERE img_id in (52, 123)
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```